# possible I am writing the wrong method for what i am doing in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I honestly could not think of a title...anyways

I am trying to create a type

```c#
public enum AssemblyType{
    Name = "NameOfFile.dll",
  }
```

In then in the unity inspector I would have a list of this type

```c#
public List<AssemblyType> requiredAssemblies = new List<AssemblyType> ();
```

And my expectation is that I will see a list where I can set a list of dropdown boxes to the Name of the `AssemblyType`

For example this
[image]

Inside of this
[image]

*In case you dont get the image*
`Day Colours` would be the list `requiredAssemblies` and `size` would be like `Culling Mask` on the first image

Sorry forgot what went wrong with the above method

This method returns this error in unity
`Assets/Scripts/WebSharp.cs(21,16): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type`string' to `int'`

sorry my problem was clearly stated

from the error I would(as anyone i hope) realize that an `enum` is an `int` value

My question what should I be replacing the `enum` with since a `string` cannot exist outside of a class

Comment: Enums can't be strings...

Comment: yes I got that im asking what can be a string

Comment: Nothing, strings will create fields to write, you can create an enum like this: `public enum MyEnum { OneValue, OtherValue }` it will show a drop down with `One Value` and `Other Value` but the `.dll` part is not achievable.

Comment: A string can be a string. Maybe you are looking for a List<string>?

Comment: the string would be populated by a path to the dll file which might be long people are gonna have a hard time navigating like that. Thus why it needs a simpler name @ChristianGollhardt

Comment: Enums are effectively just a set of compile time integer constants that are related. And integer only if you do not change that. Their only purpose is to make code slightly more readable. You could map a string to a enum value (same way you can map it to any other integer value). But that is basically just a array or List wich is only remotely related to the Enum.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt That will add a text field on the editor, not a drop down as the user is asking.

Comment: Well, then maybe the `StringValueAttribute` can help you out, if an enum is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
public enum AssemblyType{
    Name = "NameOfFile.dll",
}
```

...doesn't compile. So I'm not sure what the question is.

If you're just trying to define a list of DLL names, you just need to replace this

```
public List<AssemblyType> requiredAssemblies = new List<AssemblyType> ();
```

with this

```
public List<string> requiredAssemblies = new List<string>
{
    "NameOfFile.dll",
    "NameOfOtherFile.dll",
    "Et cetera"
};
```

If you need to expose a simpler name to the user, but let the application remember the original name, you can use a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> requiredAssemblies = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    {"NameOfFile1.dll",@"c:\SomeLongPath\NameOfFile2.dll"},
    {"NameOfFile2.dll",@"c:\SomeLongPath\NameOfFile2.dll"},
    {"NameOfFile3.dll",@"c:\SomeLongPath\NameOfFile3.dll"}
};
```

..and then populate your controls using the list returned by `requiredAssemblies.Keys`. You can then use the user's selection to look up the full path in the dictionary when you need it.

Comment: the string will be more of a "path\\to\\file" so the whole goal is for the user to easily be able to select it based on a name

Comment: Edited to meet your new requirement.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thank you